# Qt cant find the required header files despite of being set?

Tags: qt

I am trying to create a GUI app for my already created library which resides somewhere else other than the GUI app folder.
The hierarchy is like this :

```
Main project 
     Main Project
      <sources>
     Qt Project
        GUIAPP
```

and the .pro file is configured like this :

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2015-09-18T10:56:00
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets printsupport

TARGET = Ann_network
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp \
    qcustomplot.cpp \
    ../../ArtificialNeuralNetworksProject/Layer.cpp \
    ../../ArtificialNeuralNetworksProject/Matrix.cpp \
    ../../ArtificialNeuralNetworksProject/Network.cpp \
    ../../ArtificialNeuralNetworksProject/Neuron.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
    qcustomplot.h \
    ../../ArtificialNeuralNetworksProject/Layer.h \
    ../../ArtificialNeuralNetworksProject/Matrix.h \
    ../../ArtificialNeuralNetworksProject/Network.h \
    ../../ArtificialNeuralNetworksProject/Neuron.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

And this is how the project files look :
[image]

Yet when I try to compile the source code it get the error :

```
:-1: error: dependent '..\..\..\Artificial Neural Networks Project\Neuron.h' does not exist.
```

I need to say that, nowhere in the code the string above is used.
the only place I used the directive commands are in mainwindow.cpp (GUI apps sourcecode) like this :

```
#include "../../ArtificialNeuralNetworksProject/Neuron.h"
#include "../../ArtificialNeuralNetworksProject/Layer.h"
#include "../../ArtificialNeuralNetworksProject/Network.h"
```

What is the problem here? and How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you haven't properly configured your *.pro file. You are saying you're trying to include an already coded library.

But you're including the source and the headers of this library in your code, so it's not really a separate library. Are you aware of this? I want to explicit this because I don't know if it's relevant for you or not. In my opinion, building a DLL and including headers to your GUI is the right way to follow. However, if you don't have enough experience with dependencies, it's way much easier to copy/paste your library into your project.

That being said, I suggest to move your folder 'ArtificialNeuralNetworksProject' at the same level of your *.pro file and change it like this:

```
HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
    qcustomplot.h \
    ArtificialNeuralNetworksProject/Layer.h \
    ...
```

Same for SOURCES. You should read the documentation for QMAKE: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#includepath

> INCLUDEPATH
>
> Specifies the #include directories which should be searched when compiling the project.

If you don't want to change your folders on the filesystem, there is always a solution. But it doesn't seem normal to me to have dependant files not in the directory where the rest of the source code is located.

```
ArtificialNeural = C:/Users/<you>/<some path>/ArtificialNeuralNetworksProject/

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD
INCLUDEPATH += $$ArtificialNeural
```

EDIT: so if you plan to make one or more DLLs, then you could do the following project structure:

```
Project
   ├─────LibA
   ├─────LibB
   └─────MainGUI
```

**Project.pro:**

```
TEMPLATE = subdirs
CONFIG += ordered
SUBDIRS += LibA \
    LibB \
    MainGUI
```

**LibA.pro** and LibB.pro and so on:

```
DEFINES += LIB_A
TEMPLATE = lib
```

**MainGUI.pro:**

```
TEMPLATE = app
LIBS += -L$$OUT_PWD/../LibA/ -lLibA -L$$OUT_PWD/../LibB/ -lLibB 
( or -L$$OUT_PWD/../LibA/{debug|release}/ )

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../LibA $$PWD/../LibB
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../LibA $$PWD/../LibB
```

For MSVC, you have to deal explicitly with imported / exported symbols. So in each shared library that you want to write, create a tiny header:

**lib_a_global.h:**

```
#ifndef LIBRARY_GLOBAL_H
#define LIBRARY_GLOBAL_H

#if defined(A_LIBRARY)
#undef A_LIBRARY
#define A_LIBRARY Q_DECL_EXPORT
#else
#define A_LIBRARY Q_DECL_IMPORT
#endif

#endif // LIBRARY_GLOBAL_H
```

In each of your classes of LibA, add the A_LIBRARY. For example, in "neuralnetwork.h":

```
#ifndef NEURALNETWORK_H
#define NEURALNETWORK_H
#include "lib_a_global.h"

class A_LIBRARY NeuralNetwok {
 public:
   // etc
}

#endif // NEURALNETWORK_H
```

Finally, you can use you library like in your GUI and you just have to include the files you want. If in you GUI you want to instanciate NeuralNetwork class, then:

```
#include <neuralnetwork.h>

   // ...
NeuralNetwork *nn = new NeuralNetwork(this);
nn->awesomeMethod();
```

Comment: Thanks, But since I am developing the library as well, I dont plan on making it a dll at the moment, it just add unnecessary complication on the testing phase, thats why I am using the exact headers/souce files. 
I cant (and shouldnt) merge the two projects. the library will later be compiled into a dll as you already mentioned, and this GUI is just a test bed for such library. 
I'll get the include path a try and see if it works

Comment: I have edited my post to provide a complete example to build and run the library and the gui at the same time.

Comment: Thanks:)  thats a thorough answer ;)